# Django queryset filter filefield not empty

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter a queryset, to exclude the one with no file. And I can't get it work, except by numberless iterations.

```
class Something(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    file = models.FieldField(upload_to="files", null=True, blank=True)
```

Then, to get the one with a file

```
 # this give me all objects
 Something.objects.exclude(file__exact='')
 
 # this is a valid solution, but hell, something easier should exist, 
 something_with_files = set()
 for s in Something.objects.all():
    if s.file:
        something_with_files.add(s)
```

What is the real solution to this?

PS: working on PostGres, I don't know if that can change anything at that point.

Comment: When you say `file = models.FieldField(...` do you mean `file = models.FileField(...`? `FieldField` does not exist in Django.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Exact is unnecessary here:

```
Something.objects.exclude(file='')
```

Comment: In case it's useful for others, I also had to also exclude `file__exact=None` using `Something.object.exclude(Q(file='') | Q(file__exact=None))`

Answer (score 10):

There are better options, I think:

```
from django.db.models import Q    

Something.objects.filter(~Q(file__isnull=True))
```

or

```
Something.objects.exclude(file__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Yes it does, the following two ways render the same count():
(1) using the django.db.models.Q object with an excluded filter ~Q()
(2) using .exclude() with isnull=True.
That is, when null=True and blank=True in the model as mentioned in the start post

Answer (score 7):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
objects = MyModel.objects.exclude(
    Q(file='')|Q(file=None)
)
```

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/filefield.html

Answer (score 1):

I think we can directly filter out null values using:

```
Something.objects.filter(file__isnull=False)
```

In filter, you can give multiple values but in the exclude clause, you can't give multiple values. you must have to use chaining with exclude.

for more details of Django filter and exclude you can refer this [link](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52745575.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Your field allows nulls, so I guess the ones without files have the field as null, not the empty string. Try this:

```
Something.objects.exclude(file=None)
```